# "no exception to this rule"

Tags: phrases

I want to express a rule in general and then notice that this rule involves me as well. Is the following sentence, grammatically and literally correct?

> In my city, people generally follow their parent's job, and I am no exception to this rule.

Comment: Google Books claims "about 790 results" for [...and I am no exception to this...](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22and+I+am+no+exception+to+this%22) What makes you think there might be something "wrong" with it?

Comment: An idiomatic way of saying that children engage in the same work as their parents is **follow in their parents' footsteps**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your example sentence is written correctly. You make a general statement (***people generally follow their parents' job***), and then you say you don't break that rule.

***Exception to the rule*** is a common phrase, and it means "something that is different from the rest." (You can see a definition here: https://www.englishbaby.com/vocab/word/13395/exception-to-the-rule)

Because it's so common, it's natural to add "no" to the beginning of the phrase to negate the meaning. Therefore, it is fine to say ***I am no exception to the rule*** when you mean to say you are no different from the rest.